# Why won't port forwarding work for Rust server hosting on an ASUS router?

Tags: hosting, rust

[image]I matched the port in the server's batch file with the port in the router and it still won't host publically. My IPv4 matches the one shown in the command prompt. It is not a problem with the actual Rust server, so what do I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is Rust the game name?

Comment: @pinckerman yes

Comment: Have you checked the "Firewall" tab there? It's also possible it's blocked by your ISP, in which case there's nothing you can do.